# Show that $\mathcal{T}=\{U\subseteq X: \text{ U is a union of sets in B}\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$ is a topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $\mathcal{T}=\{U\subseteq X: \text{ U is a union of sets in }\beta\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$ is a toplogy on $X$
>
> $\beta$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying:
>
> 1. For each $x\in X$ there is a $B\in \beta$ such that $x\in B$
> 2. If $B_1,B_2\in \beta$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, then there is a set $B_3\in \beta$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$
>
> My definition of topology is that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal{T}$, closure under arbitrary unions and closure under finite intersection.

1. $\emptyset,X\in \mathcal{T}$ are clear

since $\emptyset\in \mathcal{T}$

and $X=\cup B$ since every $B\subseteq X$ and for every $x\in X$, $x\in B$ for some $B\in \beta$. So $X\in \mathcal{T}$

2. The $\bigcup U_\alpha=\bigcup \cup B$ is clearly a union of $\beta$ sets.
3. Let $V_1,...,V_k\in \mathcal{T}$

then $\overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}V_i=\overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}\bigcup B$

What I want to do is use property 2. and use this property of sets $P\cap(A\cup B)=(P\cap A)\cup (P\cap B)$.

To break the intersection into a union of paired intersections, which then would give me a union of $\beta$ sets. But I'm not sure this will work with arbitrary unions.

So I instead tried:

Let $x\in \overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}V_i$

then for every $i\in \{1,...,k\}$, $x\in V_i$

then $x\in \bigcup B_i$ where $B_i\subseteq V_i$ and $B_i\in \beta$

then $x\in B_i$ for some $B_i\subseteq V_i$, $B_i\in \beta$

I'm not sure how to continue this.

Comment: adding $\emptyset$ explicitly is unnecessary: it is the union of the empty subfamily of $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection property needs only to be shown for $k=2$.
So let $V_1=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ and $V_2=\bigcup_{j\in I}B_j$.
Then
$$V_1\cap V_2= \bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\cap \bigcup_{j\in I}B_j=\bigcup_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(B_i\cap B_j)$$
Unfortunately, $B_i\cap B_j$ need not be in $\beta$. However, it suffices to show that $B_i\cap B_j\in \mathcal T$. By the second property, for each $x\in B_i\cap B_j$, there exists $B_3=B_3(x)\in\beta$ with $x\in B_3(x)\subseteq B_i\cap B_j$. It follows that $$B_i\cap B_j=\bigcup_{x\in B_i\cap B_j}B_3(x)\in\mathcal T$$
and ultimately $V_1\cap V_2\in\mathcal T$.